# how do you write a regular expression to ignore the white space between quotation marks and have it saved as 1 string

Tags: c

so I'm trying to get a string from a file that is in quotation marks and has a space between the two words
so something like this "john doe" and I'm trying to save it into a single string variable, but instead, fscanf only saves the first word, I was wondering how can I save both words into one variable instead of 2

data.txt

*"john doe"*

main.c

```
FILE * infile = fopen("data.txt","r");
    if(infile == NULL){
        printf("error");
        return -1;
    }
char username[20];
fscanf(infile, "%s", username);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering how can I save both words into one variable instead of 2

`fscanf(infile, "%s", username);` only saves non-white-space input.

Read a *line* of file input with `fgets()`.  Notes that names can be quite [long](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+name&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS879US879&oq=longest+name&aqs=chrome..69i57.1859j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on).

```
#define NAME_SIZE 64     // Longest _expected_ name size

char username[NAME_SIZE * 2]; // Use a generous buffer
if (fgets(username, sizeof username, infile)) {
  // Look for "name"
  char *start = strchr(username, '\"');
  char *end = start ? strchr(start + 1, '\"') : NULL;
  if (end)  {
    printf("Username:<%.*s>\n", (int) (end - start - 1), start);

    // Additional code perhaps to:
    // trim spaces
    // Validate a length limit
    // Check character set - I'd accept at least A-Z, A-z, -, ', ., space, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: would something like this fscanf(infile, " \"%[^\"]\" ", username) also work, or is there something wrong with this method?

Comment: @Mas_T `fscanf(infile, " \"%[^\"]\" ", username) `  works almost OK when input is well formed - something robust code does not assume.  `fscanf(infile, " \"%[^\"]\" ", username) ` can read more than the end of line, may read more than one line when leading lines are only whitespace, is as bad as [gets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359) - it lacks a width limit. It is also difficult to recover from errant input.  Is quite bad if only 1 `'\"'` exist.  Your call.